# C# Showing all rows from a database table to DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagrid

I have been searching around for a while on examples on how to
display multiple or all rows from a table. A lot of examples I
have found were making it difficult for me to execute it properly 
because of the database connections and query strings..

I use my own database class with premade query functions. So in my form I have this:

```
userInfo = searchBox.Text;
string dateResult = Database.databaseAccess.GetColumnData(HLlib.ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING, userInfo, "date", "username", userInfo, true);
string ipResult = Database.databaseAccess.GetColumnData(HLlib.ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING, userInfo, "ip", "username", userInfo, true);
string userResult = Database.databaseAccess.GetColumnData(HLlib.ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING, userInfo, "username", "username", userInfo, true);
string hwidResult = Database.databaseAccess.GetColumnData(HLlib.ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING, userInfo, "hwid", "username", userInfo, true);
string pcResult = Database.databaseAccess.GetColumnData(HLlib.ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING, userInfo, "pcname", "username", userInfo, true);
```

(userInfo is a textbox that contains the name (table) that's being searched.)

The function for getting data in that format goes as follows:

```
public string GetColumnData(ValueType valueType, string tableName, string col, string colTwo, string equalsVal, bool compare)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        string colData = "";
        try
        {
            string query = "";
            if (compare)
                query = "SELECT `" + col + "` FROM `" + tableName + "` WHERE `" + colTwo + "`='" + equalsVal + "';";
            else
                query = "SELECT `" + col + "` FROM `" + tableName + "`";
            using (connection = new MySqlConnection(Hash.RunDecryption()))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    using (dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            switch (valueType)
                            {
                                case ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING:
                                    colData = dataReader.GetString(0);
                                    break;

                                case ValueType.VALUETYPE_INT16:
                                    colData = dataReader.GetInt16(0).ToString();
                                    break;

                                case ValueType.VALUETYPE_INT32:
                                    colData = dataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                    break;

                                case ValueType.VALUETYPE_INT64:
                                    colData = dataReader.GetInt64(0).ToString();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (dataReader.NextResult())
                        {
                            colData = "";
                            while (dataReader.Read())
                            {
                                switch (valueType)
                                {
                                    case ValueType.VALUETYPE_STRING:
                                        colData = dataReader.GetString(0);
                                        break;

                                    case ValueType.VALUETYPE_INT16:
                                        colData = dataReader.GetInt16(0).ToString();
                                        break;

                                    case ValueType.VALUETYPE_INT32:
                                        colData = dataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                        break;

                                    case ValueType.VALUETYPE_INT64:
                                        colData = dataReader.GetInt64(0).ToString();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Failed to retrieve data!", "Error!", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            dataReader.Close();
            CloseConnection(connection);
        }
        finally
        {
            dataReader.Close();
            CloseConnection(connection);
        }
        return colData;
    }
```

Now that is explained, what I am trying to do is display every row in the selected table
from the bottom to the top, or order by date (one column shows date/time)

I already have my columns added to DataGrid which are: date, ip, uid, hid, pname.

Same format that I have in the database table.

Can anyone help me by providing an example on how to execute this properly?

Comment: Need more info. How are you executing the query? What is the result stored in? Seems like it would be pretty simple if you are filling a DataTable, but it sounds like you are using some sort of custom object instead?

Comment: I edited my question and added the query function I use to get data from the database. The results are in the above strings that hold the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this at the end of your query string:

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: That is helpful, although I am still looking for how to print out all the rows to datagrid instead of just the last row

Comment: Your query is correct, it will print all the rows if your specified condition satisfies more than one rows. Execute it directly on the `MySQL` and check how many rows this query returns

Answer (score 0):

With Ado.net you can do processing data on the client as well. If your table is not too large, you can load its contents into Datatable. Then you can use DataView or Datatable capabilities to Select specific rows. Datatable can execute selects with filters just like DB engine. Look into ado.net datatable object reference on MSDN

Comment: It's a pain in the ass to use DataTable because it requires you to use the SqlCommand which doesn't execute right from my Database class I use for global functionallity. It's annoying to use individual queries from it. I'm just trying to find a simple Fill example with how I use my db class

Comment: Good design is to abstract your command object, etc, even database object. Then it wouldn't be matter what database you connected to. And I still don't understand how is DataTable requires SqlCommand. It could be IDataAdapter.Fill...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out a way to use it, I don't know why I didn't try this before..

My whole issue was just trying to get the connection open so I can print the data.
Ended up with this working:

```
userInfo = searchBox.Text;

        MySqlConnection connection = null;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + userInfo + " ORDER BY date DESC;";
        userGrid.Rows.Clear(); 

        using (connection = new MySqlConnection(Hash.RunDecryption()))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                userGrid.DataSource = null;
                DataSet dt = new DataSet();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(dt);
                userGrid.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Thanks all who helped, especially the order by date